# Adding a class to a package from a dependency with maven

Tags: python, python-3.x, ycsb

I'm trying to run [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB) on windows. There's a python script in the bin folder to run it.

[Here](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/bin/ycsb) are the contents of the file. When I run it in cygwin on windows I get:

```
$ ./bin/ycsb load basic -P workloads/workloada
  File "./bin/ycsb", line 51
  print "Usage: %s command database [options]" % sys.argv[0]
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have looked everywhere to see what's wrong but can't find anything.
I've tried single quotes, escaping the quotes and "".format()

Python version 3.3.0

Comment: It looks like it expects Python 2 rather than Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I'll change versions to see if it works.